# I'm trying to install Spree on my Mac with Rails 1.9.2 - I'm getting an error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, installation, spree

I'm doing a local install on Mac OSX of Spree (a Ruby-based ecommerce package) following the tutorial on [this page](http://spreecommerce.com/resources/quick-start).

I'm using RVM to run Ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3.0.3. I run "gem install spree" successfully to load spree version 0.40. But when I run "Gem Install Spree" I get the following message. Can anyone help?

```
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:335:in `bin_path': can't find executable spree for spree-0.40.0 (Gem::Exception)
 from /usr/bin/spree:19
```

Also, when I run "Gem list spree" I get an empty list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: Not sure why you are capitalizing the commands but it's not necessary
Second: your error is pointing to 1.8. Make sure you run:

```
$ rvm use 1.9.2
```

You can create a .rvmrc file in the directory of the project to always contain the correct environment

```
echo "rvm 1.9.2" > .rvmrc
```